# How do I dynamically create rows and columns using Bootstrap/Angular2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ngfor

I need to use *ngFor and content inserted from a component into my DOM depending on dynamic size of an array of contents.

I am trying to achieve this structure: A row with 3 elements on lg-12, 2 elements on md/sm and 1 element on xs without knowing in advance how many event items will be drawn out of a list from the backend query. Coded statically for example it looks like this for one line, but if I add a second line then when it collapses to 2 on md/sm there is 2 elements on one line, one element on the second line, and repeating instead of 2 elements on each line so it looks dumb.

```
  <div class="eventList container-fluid" id="eventList">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <app-event [event]="event"></app-event>
                  <app-event [event]="event"></app-event>
                  <app-event [event]="event"></app-event>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Where each element app-event element is:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 single-event-item eventResult"> 
    ... content
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Template**

```
<div class="eventList container-fluid" id="eventList">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
              <app-event *ngFor="let event of events" [event]="event"></app-event>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component** (where you retrieve your events)

This is an example as you don't mention how you retrieve your events.

```
add(event): void {
    this.someService.create(event)
      .then(event => {
        this.events.push(event); //update your array of events
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Ya that template code is very close to what I had written and not tested (div class="col-lg-12", app-event *ngFor="let event of events" [event]="event" /app-event)
 but I am very inexperienced with bootstrap so I thought it would give me trouble by not being able to distinguish between when one row ended and the next began but I guess that works if you just pass in a whole bunch of column items.

Comment: how do I mark your answer as the answer to this thread? I can't see a button which does that? Perhaps I am too low reputation to have access to that feature.

Comment: I have no idea. If the answer solve your issue that's all that matter :)